# How add Laravel 8 error pages 403, 404, 500, 503

Tags: php, laravel

I have many routs in my project. Other for frontend and others for backend.
I need add error pages 403, 404, 500, 503 for my admin.

My routs structure:

1. Routers:

- admin
  -- auth
  -- client
  -- user
- common
- front
  -- auth
  -- home

How can I add error pages only for my admins?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Laravel error pages are pre-packaged blade templates, you can publish and edit them according to your liking:

`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-errors`

Once done, you will see the error pages in `resources/views/errors`
e.g `resources/views/errors/404.blade.php`

You can then edit these templates, add conditioning for your routes/admins as well as modify the content that's shown on those pages.

One e.g can be:

```
@if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'admin')) 

// your custom template here 
@endif
```

Comment: this works in laravel 8.x also. Thanks